# Launch photoshop action using code

Tags: command-line, photoshop, photoshop-script

Is it possible to launch Photoshop action using code? I mean launch the action in Photoshop via a batch file? Or something like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Newer versions of Photoshop (CS5 and CS6 are the only ones I've worked with) support a feature called `Droplets` that lets you create executables to run a set of actions.

Check [here](http://www.photoshoplab.com/droplets-for-the-lazy.html) for detailed information on creating and running the droplet. Will update this answer with the steps shortly.

Answer (score 2):

I believe so but I have not tried it myself. The PS6 JavaScript API has a method called doAction() that might be what you are looking for.

http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/photoshop/pdfs/cs6/Photoshop-CS6-JavaScript-Ref.pdf