# photoshop auto color, tone, contrast from command line

Tags: user-interface, command-line, photoshop

Problem, I have more than 1000 pictures in folder. I want to run photoshop or any program, that can set auto tone, auto contrast and auto color to these images from commandline or GUI as long as I can do this for all images.

solutions can be for all OS (win, linux, OS X)

I have tried macros, but that requires to open every image and launch macro.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop Actions or Scripts are probably your best approach here, or Droplets on CS5+, as Photoshop isn't intended to be run headless. Here are a few discussions where a similar question was asked.

[Using PhotoShop Action/Scripts in command line](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1445540) - Adobe Forums
[Launch Photoshop Action using code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14965163/launch-photoshop-action-using-code) - StackOverflow
[Running Photoshop from the command line](http://ps-scripts.com/bb/viewtopic.php?t=515) - PS Scripts Forum (possible solution)

The short answer, is no. There are ways to perform batch actions, but you have to do it Photoshop's way; you can't directly access things like Curves, or Exposure tools via the command line.