# Shell Execute Several Files at Once

Tags: c#, shell

I have these psd files:

1.psd - 2.psd - 3.psd

I need to open these three psd files with photoshop (shell executing) at once. I mean after opening photoshop those 3 psd files should be opened in it.

How can I do this using c#?
Currently I have this code:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("1.psd");
psi.UseShellExecute = true;
Process.Start(psi);
```

But it is just for one psd file and I need to open every psd file one by one.

Comment: that is the only way.

Comment: Is there a problem repeating that 3 times for the 3 files? You can't really make the shell execute several files at once with a single command.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14965163/launch-photoshop-action-using-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does Photoshop support providing the filenames on the command line? If so, launch the PhotoShop process and provide the filenames as arguments. Here's an example of launching Notepad++ with multiple files, just replace the executable and file paths with yours.

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Notepad++.exe");
psi.Arguments = "Text1.txt Text2.txt Text3.txt";
psi.UseShellExecute = true;
Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: Thank you Craig. I know something like this is possible, But I need to ignore Photoshop's path which may be different in other systems.

Comment: Is there a way you could interrogate the registry or examine the file system to find the path to the executable? I don't have Photoshop so I can't try this myself. Alternatively, can you have the user configure your application to supply the location of the Photoshop executable? There are other ways to skin that cat.

Comment: Yeah Craig Seems I have to use Registry. Thank you Man. Accepted :)

Comment: http://paratechnical.blogspot.fr/2011/01/finding-path-to-installed-application.html

Comment: @Stranger: Just be aware that that technique is not foolproof. For example, I have Beyond Compare, ShareX, and Paint.NET (to name three I picked at random, there are others) all installed on my machine and none of them show up in that part of the registry. You should probably have a fallback of asking the user for the location of the executable if you can't find it or the value is blank when you look in the registry.